# Windows Virtual key to ASCII mapping

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Below is a simple and standard Windows Hook key code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        pStruct->vkCode;//It's the virtual key
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(keyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

HHOOK keyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, theApp.m_hInstance, NULL);
```

`pStruct->vkCode` is the virtual key code for the key is pressed. It's correct for **letters**, for example, when you press 'a', the code value is 0x41 which is 'A'.

But it's not correct for some punctuations, for example, when you press '-', the code value is 0xBD rather than its ASCII value 0x2D.

I looked up 0xBD, it's the [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) VK_OEM_MINUS.

How do I convert this virtual key code (0xBD) to the ASCII code (0x2D)?

I remember there is a Windows API to do the mapping, but I can't remember its name.

Comment: I believe you may be looking for [MapVirtualKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) with the `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR` argument. The function [`ToAscii`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-toascii) may also be of interest.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, yes I tested it and it fulfilled well. Thank you!
I'm just amazed there was no one had asked this question before on stackoverflow. I had thought this quesion would be closed as duplicated. :D

Comment: I did notice that after following your link to the virtual key code reference, (if using a wide-enough browser) there's a table of contents in which [About Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-and-character-translations) is listed... Then again, my inclination would be to head right to the [Keyboard Input Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/keyboard-input-functions) and see if anything of the names contain "VirtualKey" or "Ascii" or something else that looks promising... ;)